# installing openssh-server without an internet connection

Tags: internet, gnome-terminal, openssh

Currently we have been given an old server with the OS ubuntu. To work at it without always physically being there I wanted to access it with the software putty, but I haven't installed "openssh-server" and can't get it with the usual command because there is no internet connection. Is it possible to download the file on a usb stick and then somehow install it? By the way I can only work woth the terminal. If anyone knows how to solve this, I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 2):

This Q [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline) has a crazy amount of "offline reposiory" type apps.

But ***if you can run an online `apt-get update`*** a basic answer would be [found here (if you've got Synaptic available)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1005/129271)

1. Select packages to install in Synaptic
2. File -> Generate package download script
3. Run script on an internet-connected (linux/wget enabled) computer
4. Take downloaded .deb files back to target computer and run `sudo dpkg -i [debfiles]` or `sudo dpkg -i -R [dir with debfiles]`

And this other answer about using "simulation" mode (`apt-get -s install packagename`) to see which packages to download may be helpful too, in case Synaptic isn't available. https://askubuntu.com/a/147606/129271